# Failed to install 'Contextify' in Flux-todomvc example.

Tags: node.js

While trying to run facebook's todomvs example for flux, in the first step of npm install I got this error .

Failed at the contextify@0.1.14 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild

I tried this with node version 4.1.1 earlier but rolling back to  0.12.7 did not help as well. How to solve this issue and make this thing running.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely due to NAN upgrade related to node 4.0. See this issue: https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/issues/180

You can try removing all local modules and installing contextify by using:

```
npm i 'contextify@rvagg/contextify#nan2'
```

This solution worked for me. (I'm using Node 4.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows XP/Vista/7, node-gyp requires Python 2.7 and Visual Studio 2010.

For the full installation guide and for other Operating Systems, look at:

> https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation